# Non-conservative electric fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, conservative-field

When magnetic flux is changed linked with the coil the the electric field is produced inside the coil. But this electric field is non-conservative field whereas the electric field produced by the static charge is conservative. Why when the magnetic flux is changed linked with the coil electric field induced is nonconservative? Why a static charge produce conservative Field?

Answer (score 0):

For a vector field to be conservative (in this case, the vector field will be your electric field), you want the circulation around any closed loop to be $0$. Mathematically, you want $$\oint_{\mathcal{C}} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} = 0$$ for any closed loop $\mathcal{C}$.

Faraday's law states the following for an electric field generated by a changing magnetic flux: $$\oint_{\mathcal{C}} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} = -\frac{\partial \Phi_B}{\partial t}$$

where $\Phi_B$ is the magnetic flux through the region bounded by $\mathcal{C}$. As you can see, in the presence of a changing magnetic flux, the circulation of your electric field will be non-zero. I.e., the electric field generated by the changing magnetic flux is non-conservative.

Comment: Why the electric field made by the changing magnetic flux is nonconservative. What is inside the electric field made by the changing magnetic flux that is not in the electric field made by electric charge.